# fusionar columnas con nombres próximos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con columnas duplicadas: tienen el mismo nombre o casi el mismo nombre. Me gustaria fusionar esas columnas. Por ejemplo hay

```
New Right,   New Rights
Initiative Group,    Initiative group
Movement for Fair Georgia,   Movement for a Fair Georgia
```

Aqui es una parte de la dataframe :

```
>>> df_sum.head()
index   Map Level   Precinct ID Precinct Name   Average votes per minute (08:00-12:00)  Average votes per minute (12:00-17:00)  Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)  Christian Democratic Alliance   Christian Democratic People's Party Christian-Democratic Movement   Democratic Movement – United Georgia    Election    European Democrats  Free Georgia    Freedom Party   Future Georgia  Georgian Dream  Georgian Group  Georgian Politics   Hope party  Initiative Group    Initiative group    Invalid Ballots (%) Labour  Labour Council of Georgia   Labour Party    Merab Kostava Society   More Ballots Than Votes (#) More Votes Than Ballots (#) Movement for Fair Georgia   Movement for a Fair Georgia National Democratic Party of Georgia    National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia  New Right   New Rights  Our Country Overall Results Party of the Future People's Party  Public Movement Republican party    Right Wing Alliance Topadze Industrialists  Sportsman's Union   Total Voter Turnout (#) Total Voter Turnout (%) Traditionalists - Our Georgia and Women's Party Union of Georgian Traditionalists   United National Movement    United Opposition
0   Precinct    1   63-1    1.38    0.83    1.01    0.4 0   0   0   2008 Parliamentary - Majoritarian   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.8 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.13    0   0   0   United National Movement    0   0   0   0   0   0   749 62.11   0   0   77.17   21.5
1   Precinct    10  63-10   0.8 0.43    0.61    0   0   0   0   2008 Parliamentary - Majoritarian   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4.77    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.95    0   0   0   United National Movement    0   0   0   0   0   0   419 70.42   0   0   71.12   23.15
```

Y las columnas :

```
>>>df_sum.columns

Index([' Map Level', ' Precinct ID', ' Precinct Name',
       'Average votes per minute (08:00-12:00)',
       'Average votes per minute (12:00-17:00)',
       'Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)',
       'Christian Democratic Alliance', 'Christian Democratic People's Party',
       'Christian-Democratic Movement', 'Democratic Movement – United Georgia',
       'Election', 'European Democrats', 'Free Georgia', 'Freedom Party',
       'Future Georgia', 'Georgian Dream', 'Georgian Group',
       'Georgian Politics', 'Hope party', 'Initiative Group',
       'Initiative group\t', 'Invalid Ballots (%)', 'Labour',
       'Labour Council of Georgia', 'Labour Party', 'Merab Kostava Society',
       'More Ballots Than Votes (#)', 'More Votes Than Ballots (#)',
       'Movement for Fair Georgia', 'Movement for a Fair Georgia',
       'National Democratic Party of Georgia',
       'National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia', 'New Right',
       'New Rights', 'Our Country', 'Overall Results', 'Party of the Future',
       'People's Party', 'Public Movement', 'Republican party',
       'Right Wing Alliance Topadze Industrialists', 'Sportsman's Union',
       'Total Voter Turnout (#)', 'Total Voter Turnout (%)',
       'Traditionalists - Our Georgia and Women's Party',
       'Union of Georgian Traditionalists', 'United National Movement',
       'United Opposition'],
      dtype='object', name='index')
```

Como pueden verlos hay tambien tabulacion en los nombres : `'Initiative group\t'`

Pienso que tengo que hacer una función como la siguiente:

```
df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver el porcentaje de similitud entre los encabezados y unir los que sean similares.
En [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings) pregunta de SO dicen una manera, que adaptada a tu problema podría quedar así:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


similitud = 0.9  # He puesto un porcentaje de similitud del 90%

def comparar(a, b, similitud):
    parecido = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    print(parecido)
    return True if parecido >= similitud else False

comparar('New Right', 'New Rights', similitud)  # Similitud del 0.9473684210526315
comparar('Initiative Group', 'Initiative group', similitud)  # Similitud del 0.9375
comparar('Movement for Fair Georgia', ' Movement for a Fair Georgia', similitud)  # Similitud del 0.9433962264150944
```

Podrías comparar los encabezados y unir los que devuelvan `True`